# Haproxy: trouble using reqrep & use-server rules together

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to consolidate several backend blocks into one using `use-server` rules. I have requests for `webadmin.example.org` with various URL paths going to the same backend, & am trying to get these requests to go to different servers based on the URL paths. It is partially working, but failing in some cases. Haproxy 1.8.8 on Ubuntu 18.04. Here is my configuration:

```
backend webadmin
  # Tried both of these; it balances between servers otherwise.
  #balance source
  balance hdr(host)
  acl path:phpmyadmin path_beg -i /phpmyadmin
  acl path:phppgadmin path_beg -i /phppgadmin
  acl path:rabbitmq path_beg -i /rabbitmq
  acl path:rcmdr path_beg -i /rediscommander
  reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)rabbitmq[/]?(.*) \1\2 if path:rabbitmq
  reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)rediscommander[/]?(.*) \1\2 if path:rcmdr
  use-server rcmdr:00 if path:rcmdr
  use-server rabbitmq:00 if path:rabbitmq
  use-server nginx:00 if path:phpmyadmin || path:phppgadmin
  # Tried these too.
  #use-server rabbitmq:00 if { path_beg -i /rabbitmq }
  #use-server nginx:00 if { path_beg -i /phpmyadmin } || { path_beg -i /phppgadmin }
  #use-server rcmdr:00 if { path_beg -i /rediscommander }
  server rabbitmq:00 localhost:15672 maxconn 10000 check fall 3 rise 2
  server rcmdr:00 localhost:6670 maxconn 10000 check fall 3 rise 2
  server nginx:00 localhost:6669 maxconn 10000 check fall 3 rise 2
```

What I experience is that requests for `path:phpmyadmin` and `path:phppgadmin` matching ACLs go to the proper server (Nginx, where the URL paths are sorted out to the correct applications), but requests for the other two ACLs seem to ignore the `use-server` rules, & just go to whatever server is defined first in the list of rules (or if using a round-robin balance mode, every request is routed to a different backend, ignoring the `use-server` rules).

If I eliminate the `reqrep` rules, every request is routed properly according to the `use-server` rules. Unfortunately, I need these rules so that the backend servers respond to requests properly (i.e., they shouldn't see the subpath URLs because they don't know anything about them, they are just being used to route within Haproxy).

So, can I use the `reqrep` & `use-server` rules together? If so, how?

Comment: ACLs don't work the way you seem to assume they do.  They are re-evaluated each time they are tested, so since `reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)rabbitmq[/]?(.*) \1\2 if path:rabbitmq` *changes the request path* to make the `path:rabbitmq` ACL **no longer true**, `use-server rabbitmq:00 if path:rabbitmq` does not match it.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Can you see any way to do reqrep stripping & use-server routing in the same backend? I don't suppose the order of the rules matters either, since placing the reqrep lines after the use-server lines also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I rigged up something that works for me using variables. As @Michael - sqlbot mentioned, I had assumed ACLs were similar to pass-by-value variables, so that you could stash values in there & use them even if the source of the value changes. And I wasn't aware that Haproxy had a `set-var` feature. I also looked at Lua options but opted for this since it does what I need it to do.

```
frontend public
  # ... bind, basic setup, etc.
  # ACLS by request path.
  acl path:rcmdr path_reg ^/rediscommander(/.*)?$
  acl path:rabbitmq path_reg ^/rabbitmq(/.*)?$
  # Set the variables here.
  http-request set-var(txn.rcmdr) bool(true) if path:rcmdr
  http-request set-var(txn.rabbitmq) bool(true) if path:rabbitmq
  acl dom:webadmin hdr_dom(host) -i webadmin.example.org
  use_backend webadmin if dom:webadmin

backend webadmin
  balance hdr(host)
  acl path:phpmyadmin path_beg -i /phpmyadmin
  acl path:phppgadmin path_beg -i /phppgadmin
  # Set the ACL if the variable was set in the frontend.
  acl path:rabbitmq var(txn.rabbitmq),bool
  acl path:rcmdr var(txn.rcmdr),bool
  use-server rcmdr if path:rcmdr
  use-server rabbitmq if path:rabbitmq
  use-server nginx if path:phpmyadmin || path:phppgadmin
  # reqrep doesn't kill our ACLs because they are set based on boolean variables
  # from the frontend, not from mutable request paths tested in the backend.
  reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)rabbitmq[/]?(.*) \1\2
  reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)rediscommander[/]?(.*) \1\2
  server rabbitmq localhost:15672 maxconn 10000 check fall 3 rise 2
  server rcmdr localhost:6670 maxconn 10000 check fall 3 rise 2
  server nginx localhost:6669 maxconn 10000 check fall 3 rise 2
```

Comment: Transaction variables are exactly the correct solution for this.  Note also that the `http-request` directives are preferred over `reqxxx`, e.g. for this, you'd use `http-request set-path`.  It's a different code path internally, should be more efficient, and errors in your config are less likely to have unintended side effects.